# jsp pass bean parameter into scriplet function

Tags: java, jsp, struts, jstl, el

On my JSP page I import a java class as

```
<%@page import="org.model.MyConstants"%>
```

In the MyConstants class I have a public function

```
public static String getBookTypeName(int bookTypeId){
    //lots of if's based on id
    String bookName = 'Fantasy';
    return bookName;
}
```

Now from my JSP page I am trying to call this function passing in a request bean value as the parameter.

Essentially one property of my bean is an integer which I used to display, now I want to display the String that goes along with it but want to do so in a way where I dont need to modify the bean and can just use my MyConstants method to get the string.

I have been outputting my bean value before using

```
<bean:write name="BookNotifyForm" property="bookTypeId" />
```

I have been able to use scriplets in the past but have never had to pass a bean value into it.

```
<c:out value="<%=MyConstants.SOME_STRING_OUTPUT %>" />
```

I think I have the idea down but the syntax is what is killing me. I believe I should be able to use c:set to store the bean variable, and then use c:out calling the method passing in the variable I stored. Something along the lines of....

```
<c:set var="bookTypeId" value="${BookNotifyForm.bookTypeId}" />

//help with syntax, trying
<c:out value="<%=MyConstants.getBookTypeName(bookTypeId) %>" /> 
<c:out value="<%=MyConstants.getBookTypeName(${bookTypeId}) %>" />
```

It must be possible to do something like this !?

Comment: This is a sample about why you should [**stop** use scriptlets](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197)

Comment: Note: the link in my comment covers how to work with `public static` methods as well.

Comment: I was just using this, but I figured there had to be a better way.
      

 <logic:equal name="BookNotifyForm" property="bookTypeId" value="1">
    Fantasy
   </logic:equal>
   <logic:equal name="BookNotifyForm" property="bookTypeId" value="2">
    Horror
   </logic:equal>
   <logic:equal name="BookNotifyForm" property="bookTypeId" value="3">
    Action
   </logic:equal>

Is this an acceptable way of doing this?

Comment: @user3013612 Not if you want to read or maintain it, no. There should already be a map of book type IDs to titles on the back end; there is zero reason to do this in the view layer.